# How to style an <hr> line wavy?

Tags: html, css, line

I'm trying to create a simple wavy or groovy line - using `<hr />`. I thought this would be super easy but perhaps I'm missing something because haven't managed it yet!

Comment: May, i know.. what do you mean wavy .. and using which tool?